# OTA обновление в android

Tags: android

Какое приложение отвечает за OTA обновление в Android?

В preference из стандартного приложения Настройки пункт "Обновление системы" выглядит так:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:key="system_update_settings" android:title="@string/system_update_settings_list_item_title" android:summary="@string/system_update_settings_list_item_summary"> <intent android:action="android.settings.SYSTEM_UPDATE_SETTINGS" /> </PreferenceScreen>
```

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Находится по пути

```
system/app/OTA-Updater.apk
```

**UPD**

Чтобы быть полностью уверенным, откройте снова это приложение, зайдите в `LogCat` и поставьте фильтр на тэг `ActivityManager` в логах вы найдёте package приложения и его активность. По package можно найти apk в системе

Comment: в AOSP нет такого

Comment: Обновил ответ .